# How to avoid script injection in search query of elastic search?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, code-injection

I have a application that uses Angularjs and have database as Elastic Search. For Elastic Search the version is 1.3.1, so dynamic scripting is enabled by default. User can add data to elastic search from the application. So while searching how to avoid the injections that is the script injection in query of elastic search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Depends how json is built, if it's something like `"{query: {match:"%s"}}"` then it's possible to pass a string to add more text to the script.
2. Check, if elasticsearch post open for everybody - you should close it
3. You should use `groovy` sandboxed scripting and limit libraries to be used.